# How do I unpair a device?

Tags: bluetooth

I'm using Android 4.2. I paired with it once and never want to again and it constantly tries to connect with my phone sucking up the power and not allowing my headset to connect.

How do I unpair it?

Answer (score 2):

You just go to Settings, Bluetooth, and delete the device.

Comment: UI designers are complete muppets. I have it under Settings>Connection>"Bluetooth (On)" which incongruously behaves not only as an on/off switch but also as a submenu-opening button, where you then get the devices which you can then "unpair". For some reason in the domain of "huh WTF?" the unpaired devices are then moved to a rubrique named "available devices." Makes complete sense. Wouldn't it be simpler to have all of this in the swipedown menu (along with some currently grievously missing info on the bluetooth connection, like crypto levels etc.)

Comment: @DavidTonhofer Often these settings are sensitive to where you touch them... Like if you press on the left side of the menu entry it opens the menu, but on the right side it toggles the service. The WiFi setting on my Pixel is like that.

Answer (score 0):

May this help you, 
Goto your **Settings** > **Bluetooth**  and select the device which you have paired then click on **Unpair**.